# Django channels integrating with django

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-channels

I'm following [django channels tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order to integrate it with django. But, at one point I confronted with error which I can't solve. In terminal Django says:

```
[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
```

I think that problem is about with these lines in tutorial:

```
We will use a channel layer that uses Redis as its backing store. To start a Redis server on port 6379, run the following command:

$ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8
```

I'm working in Linux Ubuntu 17.04 and can't run command shown in above. When I run that command ubuntu terminal says:

```
docker: command not found
```

Result is still the same after installing 'docker' with 'sudo apt-get install docker'. How can I solve this problem? Is there other way to start redis server on specified port without installing docker?

Answer (score 1):

From [the first page of the tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html):

> This tutorial also uses Docker to install and run Redis. We use Redis as the backing store for the channel layer, which is an optional component of the Channels library that we use in the tutorial. [Install Docker](https://www.docker.com/get-docker) from its official website.

So, [install docker on your ubuntu system](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/), and the command `docker` will become available.

Comment: can't install as shown in docker official website (unable to fetch some archives). But it is a problem of ubuntu, and has nothing to do with django and docker. Thank you for the help.